# var $errors in the view with the laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i use the validated method for validate request, but the var errors is empty in the view :/.

in the controller, i have:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('home'); 
})->name('home'); 

Route::group(['prefix' => 'do'], function($name = null){


Route::get('/{action}/{name?}', ['uses' => 'controllers@get', 'as' =>                                                                  'get']); 


    Route::post('/', ['uses' => 'controllers@post', 'as' => 'post' ]);

    });
});
```

for the controller, i have:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class controllers extends Controller
 {

  public function get($action, $name=null)
  {
   return view('actions.' . $action, ['name' => $name]);

  } 

  public function post(Request $request)
  {


 $this->validate($request, [
     'action' => 'required',
     'name' => 'alpha|required'
 ]);

 return view('actions.'.$request['action'] , ['action' =>        $request['action'], 'name'=>$this->transformName($request['name'])]);  
}

private function transformName($name)
{
  $add = "king ";
   return $add.strtoupper($name);
 }
}
```

and for the view, i have:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <div class="centered">
        <a href="{{route('get', ['action' => 'greet'])}}">greet</a> 
        <a href="{{route('get', ['action' => 'hug'])}}">hug</a>
        <a href="{{route('get', ['action' => 'kiss'])}}">kiss</a>
        <br >
        <br >
         @if (isset($errors) && count($errors) > 0)
       <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                {!! $errors->first() !!}
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
        @endif      
        <form action="{{ route('post')}}" method="post">
            <label for="select-action">I want to...</label>
            <select id="select-action" name="action">  
                <option value="greet">greet</option>
                <option value="hug">hug</option>
                <option value="kiss">kiss</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" name="name"> 
            <button type="submit">action</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}"> 
        </form>
    </div>
   @endsection
```

if i delete the middleware of the route, the var errors work correctly.

how i can fix this?

thanks.

Comment: Where is the code for the middleware?

Comment: the code for the middleware is in the kernel.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using latest Laravel 5.2 build, you should remove `web` middleware from `routes`. Now it applies automatically to all routes and if you're trying to add it manually, it causes different errors.

Comment: Just one more question, so that cases then used the: web middleware from routes ??

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand your question. Could you rephrase it please.

Comment: sorry, in which case then it would be used web middleware in the routes

Comment: Now `web` middleware will be used in all routes automatically.